# How to fill simple datagridview in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am using Visual Studio 2005 I have a simple problem in which I am not able to populate my datagridview with Datatable

Till now my code is a s follows

```
       this.dataGridView1.DataSource = ds1.Tables[0];
        dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns =true;
```

Can anyone help

Comment: Are you sure you have data in `ds1.Tables[0]`?

Comment: ya data is coming datatable that i want to bind

Answer (score 0):

You can pass by `BindingSource`

```
 // Set up the data source.
 var bindingSource1.DataSource = ds1.Tables[0];
 dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;
```

Answer (score 0):

try to do

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds1;
dataGridView1.DataMember = "your_table_name";
```